# Swift video replay lasts long time

Tags: ios, swift, video, avfoundation

I use the following code to load a video from my library and play it afterwards. My problem is that it's very slow and so I have to wait for the replay for about 10 sec and even then it doesn't work well.

```
func showVideo(obj: AnyObject!) {
    manager.requestAVAssetForVideo(obj as! PHAsset, options: videoOptions, resultHandler: {(avAsset: AVAsset?, audioMix: AVAudioMix?, info: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Void in
        self.url = (avAsset as! AVURLAsset).URL
        self.playVideo()
    })
}

// plays the video
private func playVideo() {
    asset = AVAsset(URL: url!)
    playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset!)

    player = AVPlayer(playerItem: self.playerItem!)

    playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.player)
    playerLayer.frame = view.frame
    view.layer.addSublayer(self.playerLayer!)

    player!.play()
}
```

And I get the object from:

```
let allVideo = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithMediaType(.Video, options: fetchOptions)
showVideo(allVideo.lastObject)
```

Answer (score 0):

To loop video I use the notification:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self
    , selector: #selector(playerItemDidReachEnd(_:))
    , name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
    , object: player.currentItem)
```

and the function:

```
func playerItemDidReachEnd(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let playerItem = notification.object {
        playerItem.seekToTime(kCMTimeZero)
    }
}
```

Comment: and where should I add the NSNotificationCenter code?

Comment: you could put it in playVideo() but don't forget to remove the observer if you intend to call playVideo() more than once